# How to send picture or file with Action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I have a chat application that uses the cable action. So how can I send pictures or files. Please help me

Comment: you could upload/save the pictures/files on the server and then send a _url_ over action cable

Comment: @maxpleaner Can you send me a link?

Comment: Another option is to encode them as Base64 strings and send them along with a filetype identifier as a chat message. On the client side you will need to create a proper file data link out of the data and perhaps unencoded the base64 string (depending on your final action).